# Find duplicate and their unique ID

Tags: mysql

This is the fruit_project table:

```
ID    FRUIT
1     Mango
2     Apple
3     Banana
4     Carrot
5     Apple
6     Banana
7     Apple
8     Banana
9     Mango
10    Apple
```

This what I tried.

```
select id, fruit, count(*) dup  from fruit_project  
group by fruit 
having dup>1
```

The result is

```
ID  FRUIT    DUP 
1   Mango    2
2   Apple    4
3   Banana   3
```

If I use GROUP_CONCAT on ID, the result will be

```
ID               FRUIT    DUP 
1,9              Mango    2
2,5,7,10         Apple    4
3,6,8            Banana   3
```

Result I need is

```
ID    FRUIT
1     Mango
2     Apple
3     Banana
5     Apple
6     Banana
7     Apple
8     Banana
9     Mango
10    Apple
```

In the result I need, the non-duplicate (4 Carrot) is not there,
and not using COUNT function. (majority in web suggest to use COUNT)
Any other way to find duplicate without COUNT?
Like conditional formatting in Excel

Comment: Just join the table to itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
select * 
from your_table t1
where FRUIT IN (select FRUIT from your_table WHERE ID != t1.ID);
```